# Copy array with extension method

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code:

```
DateTime[] localTimeArray = GetTimeData<DateTime>();
```

Now the thing is that I need to call `.ToLocalTime()` for each element in the array returned by `GetTimeData` before they are copied to the new array.

How can I go about this without having to iterate over each item manually?

Obviously the following does not work:

```
DateTime[] localTimeArray = GetTimeData<DateTime>().ToLocalTime();
```

As `GetTimeData` is from an external library I cannot add the code inside this as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Have you considered adding a parameter to `GetTimeData` such that it takes care of the `ToLocalTime` call for you (to avoid the unnecessary array allocation)?

Comment: The problem is that GetTimeData is from an external library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime[] localTimeArray = GetTimeData<DateTime>().Select(x => x.ToLocalTime()).ToArray();
```